# What is the name of the logic used in CLIPS?

Tags: clips, expert-system

I am writing a formal document about a software which uses CLIPS. I need to mention the logic (propositional, first-order, temporal etc) used in Computer science. I need to cite some reference which mentions the logic used in CLIPS. I guess it is deductive logic (a top-down approach) but I am not an expert in Logics, so any help is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the wikipedia entry for production systems, there are multiple opinions. One is that production systems do not have logical semantics and another is that forward chaining is the means of logical reasoning.